# How to Compile CSS variables with PostCss

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, postcss

I'm using React with CRA & react-app-rewired, I want to compile CSS custom properties (--*) to plain css :

From :

```
.section {
    --gap-horizontal: 10px;
}

.section .item {
    margin: 0 var(--gap-horizontal);
}
```

To something like :

```
.section .item {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Here's my
**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('postcss-preset-env')({
            stage: 1,
        }),
        require('postcss-nested'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
};
```

My build cmd :

```
postcss src/**/*.css --dir build
```

Comment: You need the next plugin postcss-css-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Grzegorz T mentioned in the comment, i had to add [postcss-css-variables](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/postcss-css-variables) plugin.

Install:

```
yarn add -D postcss-css-variables
```

Add `require('postcss-css-variables')` to **`postcss.config.js`** :

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('postcss-css-variables'),
        require('postcss-preset-env')({
            stage: 1,
        }),
        require('postcss-nested'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
};
```